# flash action script press a keyboard letter

Tags: flash, actionscript, action

hello can anyone help all i want to do is press the "a" on the keyboard and it goes to frame 2 i have the following working button but this only works for up down left right etc

```
    this.onKeyDown = function() {
if (Key.isDown(Key.SPACE)) {
desert._visible = false;
forest._visible = false;
tunnel._visible = true;
gotoAndPlay(2);
}}
```

how do i change the above so instead of SPACE i can press "a"

Answer (score 0):

You can find all available keycodes right [here](http://www.dakmm.com/?p=272). A great resource on this topic.

Comment: that looks the thing. but whats the code to implement? do i have o write a new function?

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000311.html